# Show that if a set $E$ is finite then it is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm not sure how to start. I don't know how to define $E$.

So after your comments , here is my answer , please guide me if something is wrong or doesn't make sense.

$E:= \{X_1, X_2,\dots,X_N\}$ where $N$ belongs to Natural numbers

Let the open cover $\{\Theta_i\}_{i\in I}$  be given. Since $X_n \in \bigcup_{i\in I} \Theta_i$, there exists $j\in I$ such that $X_n \in\Theta_j$.

Then $\{\Theta_i\}_{i\in J}$ is an open subcover of $E$.

Comment: Suppose that the set $E$ has $n$ many elements ...

Comment: Could a finite set have infite open subsets?

Comment: @JosephCurwen You are principally right, but it may be the case that $E$ is introduced as a subspace of some space $X$ and an open cover  is of the form $E\subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I} U_i$ and not as $E\subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I} (U_i\cap E)$.

Answer (score 2):

Take any open covering of $E$, number the points of $E$ from $1$ to $n=|E|$. Then the point $i$ is contained in some element of your cover, name it $U_i$. The collection $\{U_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is a finite subcovering.

Comment: Do you mind checking my answer after I edited the question?

Answer (score 0):

Index the elements in $E$ as $e_1, \ldots, e_m$ and take any infinite sequence $x_n \in E$. Then go through the $e_i$ one by one like this: "Are there infinitely many $n$ so that $x_n = e_i$?" No matter what the sequence $x_n$ is, the answer to your question has to be "yes" at least once as you go through $E$ (why?). Pick one of those points and call it $e_j$. Let $n_k$ be an infinite, increasing sequence of natural numbers such that $x_{n_k} = e_j$ (why are there infinitely many such $n_k$?). Now you have shown that your sequence $x_n$ has a convergent (actually constant) subsequence. Since $x_n$ was an arbitrary sequence, this means that *any* sequence in $E$ has a convergent subsequence. What does this say about compactness?